# How to pass value from client side to server side in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

how to pass the value in below script to the server side

```
// listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
FB.api('/me', function(me) {
document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
document.getElementById('Email').innerHTML = me.email;
document.getElementById('gender').innerHTML = me.gender;
document.getElementById('birth').innerHTML = me.birthday;
document.getElementById('firstname').innerHTML = me.first_name;
})
```

Comment: what value r u trying to pass?

Comment: @jade: 
Name, email, gender, brithday

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to Pass and save the Facebook User's Information values from script to server?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12457128/how-to-pass-and-save-the-facebook-users-information-values-from-script-to-serve)

Comment: @CBroe: sorry am frehser, i dont know how ask the question. so i will be carefull hereafter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In webform2.aspx

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function LoadValues(me) {
                     {

                        var Email = me.email;
                        var Name = me.name;
                        var Id = me.id;
                        var Dob = me.birthday;
                        var Gender = me.gender;
                        alert(Email)

                        document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';


                          var data2Send = '{"fbemail": '+Email+', "fbname":'+Name+', "fbid":'+Id+',"fbname":'+Dob+',"fbname":'+Name+' }';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'webform2.aspx/Testmethod',
            data: data2Send,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (arg) {console.log(arg) //call successfull
            $("#lbltxt").text(arg);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
              alert(xhr);  //error occurred
            }
        });


          }
</script>
```

In webform2.aspx.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string TestMethod(string fbid, string fbemail, string fbsex, string fbdob)
    {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader datareader;


        con = new SqlConnection(".......");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SpFacebookInfo", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FbId", fbid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FbEmail", fbemail);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FbSex", fbsex);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FbDob", fbdob);
        datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        datareader.Close();

        return fbemail;


    }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript variables exist on the client so in order to get those values into the server you'll need to execute a request from the client.You probably want an approach called AJAX. AJAX involves Javascript making requests to the server in the background of your page. You'll set up a C# web page that expects these background requests. If you use a GET request then then place the variables in the query string of your AJAX request to your new C# page. If you want to use a POST request then you'll set parameters in the data that you post to your page.

Libraries like jQuery make this kind of thing pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you for giving the idea.. I Have successfully passed the values to the server..

Comment: Why don't you provide the solution here

Answer (score 0):

Set the value in a hidden variable as u did and do a `document.myform.submit();`
 to go to Page_Load and read the variables